# Java: Turn a math equation into a String expression?

Tags: java, math, tostring, equations

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to figure out how I would write a math expression that displays the values of the variables on one line, then on the next line does the math?

Here is what I thought would work, but it just prints out the answers instead of the string representations on the top line of the addStuff() method.

```
public class DoSomeMath {
    int num1C = 3;
    int num1A = 7;
    public void addStuff(){
        //Show the Equation//
        System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + Integer.toString(num1C) + Integer.toString(num1A));
        //Show the Answer//
        System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + num1C + num1A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving the effect you want for this is even easier than you are making it:

```
//Show the Equation//
System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + num1C + "+" + num1A);
//Show the Answer//
System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + (num1C + num1A));
```

The first line concatenates them as strings, while the second line forces the integer addition via parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.  XD

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `+` operator in `System.out.println(String str)` When you use `+` sign for string's it normally does the task of appending the string in the string pool.

```
//Show the Equation//
System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + Integer.toString(num1C) + 
"+"+ Integer.toString(num1A));
//Show the Answer//
System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + " " + (num1C + num1A));
```

So understand the use of `+` arithmetic operator with Strings and integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it `+ Integer.toString(num1C) + " + " + Integer.toString(num1A)`

Any static characters you can enter as a string, and then concatenate with the variables.

Comment: How do I get the "+" sign then to go between the two variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your num1C and num1A are getting converted to Strings and appended as Strings.  Use parentheses so the math happens first, then the String append last.

```
System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + (num1C + num1A));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class DoSomeMath {
    int num1C = 3;
    int num1A = 7;
    public void addStuff(){
        //Show the Equation//
        System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + num1C + " + " + num1A);
        //Show the Answer//
        System.out.println("Adding num1C + num1A: " + (num1C + num1A));
    }
}
```